# Symfony Custom Field Template label is rendered twice

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, label

I created a custom form field called 'AgenceSelectType' which is basically an EntityType with Defaults values and a custom theme.

Every time I render a form with this Type the label gets rendered twice. This is driving me mad. What am I missing ?

Symfony 3.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 php 7.1

My fields.html.twig file :

```
    {% block agence_select_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>
                  {{label }} 
                </label> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 form-group">
                <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }} class="form-control" >
                {%- if preferred_choices|length > 0 -%}
                    {% set options = preferred_choices %}
                    {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
                    {%- if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none -%}
                        <li disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</li>
                    {%- endif -%}
                {%- endif -%}
                {%- set options = choices -%}
                {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            </select>
            </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}

{%- block choice_widget_options -%}
    {% for group_label, choice in options %}
        {%- if choice is iterable -%}
            <optgroup label="{{ group_label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}">
                {% set options = choice %}
                {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            </optgroup>
        {%- else -%}
            <option value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ choice.label }}</option>
        {%- endif -%}
    {% endfor %}
{%- endblock choice_widget_options -%}
```

And my custom type

```
class AgenceSelectType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Agence',
            'label' => 'Agence',
            'choice_label' => function ($agence) {
                    return $agence->getNom();
                },
            'required' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for relieving me from such a madness :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you displaying the form row in your view ?

If you're using `form_row(form.agence)`, it's normal behavior, because your `block agence_select_widget` includes the label, and `{{ form_row() }}` is a shortend for `form_label` + `form_widget`.
I think your `agence_select_widget` block should only contains the input view, not the label view.

If you definitely wants your `agence_select_widget` to include the label, then use `{{form_widget(form.agence) }}` to display both label and input, dont use `{{form_row() }}` (but if you do this, you're not doing it the right way).

For a good use of widget and label block, i would juste move

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>
      {{label }} 
    </label> 
</div>
```

from your `{% block agence_select_widget %}` to a new `{% block agence_select_label %}` block

Comment: You made my day thanks ! Even though the first option is cleaner, I went with the second one because the field can also be of hidden type depending on underlying data.